# Is this the right place to ask 'what is this connector?'

Tags: discussion

I have a car audio system that I'm currently trying to build an embedded system around. I have found a really strange adapter type that I don't know how to figure out what the standard is, so I can't easily purchase an adapter to integrate with it.

Is a question asking to identify this connector on-topic for this site?

Comment: Probably not, as you'll get an answer like "this is an 5 pin AMP xyz connector commonly used in automotive applications" rather than "on car x, this is the connector that goes to sensor y and has pin-out z" which is probably the kind of answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, go ahead. Plenty of other people do it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with an automotive connector [Mechanics.SE](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com) (specialized automotive stack) would be a better place for your particular question.

*p.s.* Some types of automotive connectors are cataloged [here](http://pinouts.ru/conn/proprietary/).